# scala worksheet weird function description

Tags: scala, intellij-14

I have created a *Scala Worksheet* in *Intellij Idea 14 Community Edition* and now trying to do some scala practice with basic examples.

When I create a function, the function description which I see in the worksheet compiled output shows something wierd, is something wrong with my scala compiler or Intellij or is it new way of showing function definition in *scala 2.10.6* (Note : I am not using SBT)

*Java : 1.8
, OS : Mac OSX*

```
isGoodEnough(guess: Double, x: Double) = math.abs(guess * guess - x) / x < 0.001

def improve(guess: Double, x: Double) = (guess + x / guess) / 2

def sqrtIter (guess : Double, x : Double) : Double =
  if(isGoodEnough(guess, x)) guess
  else sqrtIter(improve(guess, x), x)

def sqrt (x : Double) = sqrtIter(1, x)

sqrt(4)
```

Output shown by Scala Worksheet

```
isGoodEnough: isGoodEnough[](val guess: Double,val x: Double) => Boolean

improve: improve[](val guess: Double,val x: Double) => Double

sqrtIter: sqrtIter[](val guess: Double,val x: Double) => Double

sqrt: sqrt[](val x: Double) => Double

res0: Double = 2.000609756097561
```

**I can't undesrtand why it's showing the function names as isGoodEnough[], improve[] in the function definition/description**

Answer (score 1):

In Scala you can use generics when you want to make a function general. For example, my tail function below acts on a List, but I don't want to specify what is in the list, just the fact it is a list of something (that I'll give the placeholder A)

```
def tail[A](l: List[A]): List[A] = ...
```

When doing this, you need to tell the Scala compiler about it - you do that with the brackets before the parameters.

The [] in isGoodEnough[], improve[] is showing you that you don't have any generics involved

Comment: ok .. then this way of showing function definition might have been added in newer versions of Scala or intellij. I remember when i was practising in intellij 13 with Scala 2.9.1 then it didn't come in this way.

Comment: @Ashu I think so, it's not in my version of the repl, so I suspect it's something new in the intellij plugin

Comment: actually it's not in REPL, it coming in scala worksheet which I created in Intellij. In mine REPL too it's coming as normal.
I think I should check in Eclipse with the same scala version, that might clear the doubt, if its coming due to scala or Intellij